# Soundproofing an outdoor double pane glass door with aluminum frame

Tags: doors, sound-proofing

I live in apartment were across the street is an industrial air conditioner that runs 24/7 and makes a semi high pitched noise. The windows and sliding glass door in my living room effectively block the sound but the door to the balcony in my bedroom does not.

You can see and listen to an amplified version here. It's amplified because there is really no way to convey how loud and annoying the sound is unamplified unless we used headphones and calibrated a bunch of stuff.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOyhcFb4jf4

In the video I start in the living room at 2am and though you can hear white noise it's not so bad but then I walk into the bedroom and toward the door and you clearly hear the high pitched whine.

The door looks like it was designed to be soundproof. It's got double pane glass and then this fur like material around the inner frame the door presses against when closed.

[image]

The ridge/inner frame that this fur is attached too is slightly loose meaning if I try to move it with my hand I can feel it move say 0.1mm, just the tiniest bit, but enough to feel that it's not glued/caulked down.

My thinking is that maybe I can fix the problem by

(1) applying some kind of soundproofing caulk/sealant like Green Glue Sealant? to the joint between the inner frame that the fur is attached to and the outdoor door frame

[image]

(2) putting some kind of acoustic foam tape on the door where it touches the fur

[image]

So questions.

- Is there any chance this will work?
- What kind of caulk/sealant should I use?
- Will the foam pressing against the fur help?
- Should I remove the fur and just have the foam (ie, replace the fur with foam tape)?
- If I should remove the fur how do I remove it?

  The entire door frame has only 4-5 visible screws. It's not at all clear how any part of it comes off (more pics [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/D9vKqccjKqzjkWYM7))
- What else should I do or different solutions are there?

Comment: If it’s an apartment, will the manager allow you to add caulking, remove / add weatherstripping, etc. ?

Comment: What you’re referring to as “fur” is actually “felt”.

Comment: Before anything else - pull the door hard towards you & see if it makes even the slightest difference. Note, there's no sealed weather-bar at the bottom, so that's as likely a sound-leakage point as the peculiar fuzzy stuff round the rest of the frame [never seen an exterior door done like that] The keep in the frame doesn't look adjustable, unfortunately, to be able to close it tighter on its own.

Comment: @LeeSam, it may be felt but I've never seen furry felt. [The only felt I've ever used has no fur](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ecologicaltextiles.nl%2Fcontents%2Fen-uk%2Fp585_Product_584.html&psig=AOvVaw1nPrX_7rlzAc0v1hnWcEzo&ust=1628634920982000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCJC4zYGApfICFQAAAAAdAAAAABAK).

Comment: @tetsujin, [there is a seal at the bottom](https://photos.app.goo.gl/m5YWxWD2o73qhkLWA). Putting my ears near various areas on the door it's clear the sound is not coming through the bottom, it's coming through the felt/fur or at least through the edges of the door.

Comment: OK, didn't spot that in the earlier photos. I'd replace the 'fur' with a proper seal; but you're going to have to investigate how it's fitted. A lot of seals just run in a channel in the frame - easiest to insert before the frame is assembled, but sometimes if you can manage to get the old one out, the new one will, with a deal of patience, push-fit back into the channel. Alternatively, neoprene foam adhesive strip, though the cheap stuff does compress over time.